# Obscure Calculations in Foldy-Wouthuysen Transformation (electron in EM field)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, special-relativity, commutator, dirac-equation

I'm studying the Foldy-Wouthuysen Transformation on Bjorken-Drell's book and I got stuck strying to replicate some calculations.
First of all, introducing the transformation $\psi'=e^{iS}\psi$ we get to the equation $i\frac{\partial \psi'}{\partial t}=H'\psi'$, where
$$H'=e^{iS}\left(H-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)e^{-iS}.$$
Now we want to expand $H'$ in a series of multiple commutator ($S$ is expanded in powers of $1/m$) and Bjorken-Drell says that we get to
\begin{multline}
H'=H+i[S,H]-\frac{1}{2}[S,[S,H]]-\frac{i}{6}[S,[S,[S,H]]]\notag\\
   +\frac{1}{24}[S,[S,[S,[S,\beta m]]]]-\dot{S}-\frac{i}{2}[S,\dot{S}]+\frac{1}{6}[S,[S,\dot{S}]].
\end{multline}
So my first question is:

**(1) How do I get those coefficients for the terms that contain the derivative $\dot{S}$?** I tried to calculate the formula and got to something like $-\dot{S}-i[S,\dot{S}]+\tfrac{1}{2}[S,[S,\dot{S}]]$ and I'm pretty sure I'm missing something.

My second question is about the interpretation of the Darwin term, i.e. the last term in the final result:
\begin{multline}
 H'''=\beta\left(m+\frac{(\vec{p}-e\vec{A})^2}{2m}-\frac{\vec{p}^4}{8m^3}\right) + e\Phi -\frac{e}{2m}\beta \vec{\sigma}\cdot \vec{B}\\
 -\frac{ie}{8m^2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot \vec\nabla \times \vec{E} - \frac{e}{4m^2}\vec{\sigma}\cdot \vec{E}\times \vec{p} - \frac{e}{8m^2}\vec\nabla \cdot \vec{E}.
\end{multline}
Bjorken-Drell considers an elecron that fluctuates (because of the zitterbewegung) over distances $\delta r\simeq 1/m$ and sees a smeared out Coulomb potential, then calculates the correction as
\begin{align*}
 \langle \delta V \rangle = \langle V(r+\delta r)\rangle - \langle V(r) \rangle &= \langle \delta r \frac{\partial V}{\partial r}+\frac{1}{2}\sum_{ij}\delta r_i \delta r_j \frac{\partial^2 V}{\partial r_i \partial r_j} \rangle\\
 &\simeq \frac{1}{6}\delta r^2 \nabla^2 V \simeq \frac{1}{6m^2}\nabla^2 V.
\end{align*}
My second question is:

(2) **What is happening here? How do we calculate the man value and get to $\frac{1}{6}\delta r^2 \nabla^2 V$?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Question 1.** Bjorken and Drell are a bit careless with the notation, since in
$$
H'|\psi\rangle=\exp(iS)\left(H-i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right)\exp(-iS)|\psi\rangle
$$
$H$ acts on everything to the right (on $|\psi\rangle$, too), but $i\partial/\partial t$ only acts on $\exp(-iS)$ (this one is clear from the derivation). It would be more appropriate to write
$$
H'=\exp(iS)H\exp(-iS)-\exp(iS)\left[i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp(-iS)\right] \ .
$$
Since $S$ and $\dot{S}$ usually do not commute, one must be careful when differentiating, as e.g.
$$
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}S^2=\dot{S}S+S\dot{S}
\ \ \ , \ \ \ 
\frac{\partial}{\partial t}S^3=\dot{S}S^2+S\dot{S}S+S^2\dot{S} \ .
$$
With this in mind, it is easy to get the result to the desired order:
$$
\left[i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp(-iS)\right]=\dot{S}-\frac{i}{2}(\dot{S}S+S\dot{S})-\frac{1}{6}(\dot{S}S^2+S\dot{S}S+S^2\dot{S})+... \ ,
$$
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \exp(iS)\hspace{-1.1mm}\left[i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp(-iS)\right]\hspace{-1.1mm}
&=\hspace{-1.1mm}
\left[1+iS-\frac{1}{2}S^2+...\right]\hspace{-1.2mm}\left[\dot{S}-\frac{i}{2}(\dot{S}S+S\dot{S})-\frac{1}{6}(\dot{S}S^2+S\dot{S}S+S^2\dot{S})+...\right] \\
&=\dot{S}+\frac{i}{2}(S\dot{S}-\dot{S}S)-\frac{1}{6}(\dot{S}S^2-2S\dot{S}S+S^2\dot{S})+... \\
&=\dot{S}+\frac{i}{2}[S,\dot{S}]-\frac{1}{6}[S,[S,\dot{S}]]+... \ .
\end{aligned}
$$

A more systematic way to obtain this series is e.g. to apply the operator calculus of Feynman ([*Phys. Rev.* **84** 108 (1951)](https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.84.108)). We can write
$$
\exp(-iS)=\exp\left(-i\int_0^1\mathrm{d}uS(u)\right) \ ,
$$
where $u$ is an ordering parameter, and $S(u)$ is a symbol with a commutative algebra. Then we have
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \left[i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp(-iS)\right]
 &=
 \int_0^1\mathrm{d}v \dot{S}(v)\exp\left(-i\int_0^1\mathrm{d}uS(u)\right) \\
 &=
 \int_0^1\mathrm{d}v \exp\left(-i\int_v^1\mathrm{d}wS(w)\right) \dot{S}(v)\exp\left(-i\int_0^v\mathrm{d}uS(u)\right) \\
 &=
 \int_0^1\mathrm{d}v \exp\left(-i\int_v^1\mathrm{d}wS\right) \dot{S}\exp\left(-i\int_0^v\mathrm{d}uS\right) \\
 &=
 \int_0^1\mathrm{d}v \exp\left(-i(1-v)S\right) \dot{S}\exp\left(-ivS\right) \ ,
\end{aligned}
$$
where $\dot{S}(v)$ is the time derivative of $S(v)$ (not to be confused with the dependence on the ordering parameter $v$); after correctly ordering the symbols (parameters increasing from right to left), we reverted to the original $S$ operators, and performed the trivial integrations in the exponents. Then
$$
\begin{aligned}
 \exp(iS)\left[i\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\exp(-iS)\right]
&=
\int_0^1\mathrm{d}v \exp\left(ivS\right) \dot{S}\exp\left(-ivS\right) \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{k!}C_k(S,\dot{S})\int_0^1\mathrm{d}v v^k \\
&=
\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^k}{(k+1)!}C_k(S,\dot{S}) \ .
\end{aligned}
$$
The integrand finally had the form $\exp(iA)B\exp(-iA)$, so the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula could be applied to arrive at an expansion in terms of nested commutators:
$$
C_k(A,B)=[A,[A,...[A,B]...]] \ .
$$
This is the general form of the expansion.

**Question 2.** In this case, the notation $\langle...\rangle$ implies an angular averaging, not an expectation value in the QM sense. We average over the orientations of the fluctuations around a given point $\vec{r}$ in which the potential is evaluated:
$$
\langle \delta x_i \rangle_{\text{ang.}}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\mathrm{d}\Omega \, \delta x_i(\Omega)=0 \ ,
$$
$$
\langle \delta x_i \delta x_j \rangle_{\text{ang.}}=\frac{1}{4\pi}\int\mathrm{d}\Omega \, \delta x_i(\Omega)\delta x_j(\Omega)=\frac{1}{3}\delta r^2 \delta_{ij} \ ,
$$
where $\delta r^2=\delta x \delta x+ \delta y \delta y + \delta z \delta z\sim1/m^2$. The first derivative term thus vanishes while the second derivative term reads
$$
\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{3}\delta r^2\delta_{ij}\partial_i\partial_jV=\frac{1}{6}\delta r^2\nabla^2V\sim\frac{1}{6m^2}\nabla^2V \ .
$$